# Is there a way to create a column-wide table in beamer?

Tags: tables, beamer, two-column

I am writing a presentation using beamer class, and I want to show a table and then  split some text in two columns. I tried to use the code below, but it doesn't work, and I can't find that much information abou this in particular.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
%\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %codificação de caracteres ã é etc
\usepackage[english,portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\mode<presentation> {
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\usetheme{Luebeck}
\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Composição Química} 



\begin{table*}[H]
\centering
%\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{El. Químico} (\%) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Si} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Mn} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Cr} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Mo} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{V} & P                          & S                          \\      \hline
\textbf{Máximo}           & 1.65                   & 0.40                    & 0.50                    & 13.00                   & 0.90                    & 1.00                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.030} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.030} \\      \hline
\textbf{Mínimo}           & 1.45                   & 0.10                    & 0.15                    & 11.00                   & 0.60                    & 0.70                   & -                          & -                          \\      \hline
\end{tabular}
}


\caption{Composição Química do aço C 265}
\end{tabular}
%\end{adjustbox}
\label{cq}
\end{table*}


\column{.45\textwidth}

Carborígenos
\begin{itemize}
\item Crómio
\item Vanádio
\item Molibdénio
\end{itemize}

\column{.45\textwidth}

Alfagenos
\begin{itemize}
\item Crómio
\item Vanádio
\item Molibdénio
\item Silício
\end{itemize}




\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It's not quite clear to me. Do you want your table full-width, or in one of the columns, and which?

Comment: Offtopic comment: you do not need `\usepackage{graphicx}` in beamer as beamer itself already provides it.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems here:

- You have a opening `{` after `\mode<presentation>` but no closing brace, so I deleted that.
- `beamer` doesn't define a starred `table` environment. And it doesn't really make sense for it to do so either, `columns` in `beamer` are more like two minipages next to each other, text doesn't flow from one column to the other, as in e.g. `article`.
- When you want to use multiple columns in `beamer`, you need to wrap them in a `columns` environment, so you have e.g.

  ```
  \begin{columns}
  \column{0.4\textwidth}
  Text in first column
  \column{0.4\textwidth}
  Text in second column
  \end{columns}
  ```

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
%\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %codificação de caracteres ã é etc
\usepackage[english,portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\mode<presentation> 
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\usetheme{Luebeck}
\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Composição Química} 



\begin{table}
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{El. Químico} (\%) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Si} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Mn} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Cr} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Mo} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{V} & P                          & S                          \\      \hline
\textbf{Máximo}           & 1.65                   & 0.40                    & 0.50                    & 13.00                   & 0.90                    & 1.00                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.030} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.030} \\      \hline
\textbf{Mínimo}           & 1.45                   & 0.10                    & 0.15                    & 11.00                   & 0.60                    & 0.70                   & -                          & -                          \\      \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Composição Química do aço C 265}
\label{cq}
\end{table}

\begin{columns}
\column{.45\textwidth}

Carborígenos
\begin{itemize}
\item Crómio
\item Vanádio
\item Molibdénio
\end{itemize}

\column{.45\textwidth}

Alfagenos
\begin{itemize}
\item Crómio
\item Vanádio
\item Molibdénio
\item Silício
\end{itemize}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```